# VB.NET call a button function

Tags: database, vb.net, oop

How do i go about this code, I want to call amountpayable on the confirm purchase button but it says amount payable is not declared and I am having a hard time trying to pass the value from another function... Anyone knows a quick easy fix? I am not familiar with visual basic so if someone can share a light on this query I just want an easy one, one i can easily understand

Here is the code

```
Private Sub BtnAddOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAddOrder.Click
        Dim AddOns As String
        Dim BlackPearl As String
        Dim Oreo As String
        Dim Nata As String
        Dim CoffeeJelly As String
        Dim CreamCheese As String

        AddOns = " "
        BlackPearl = " "
        Oreo = " "
        Nata = " "
        CoffeeJelly = " "
        CreamCheese = " "


        If ChkBoxBlackPearl.Checked = True Then
            AddOns = "Black Pearl"
        End If
        If ChkBoxOreo.Checked = True Then
            AddOns = AddOns & "," & " Oreo"
        End If
        If ChkBoxNata.Checked = True Then
            AddOns = AddOns & "," & " Nata De Coco"
        End If
        If ChkBoxCoffeeJelly.Checked = True Then
            AddOns = AddOns & "," & " Coffee Jelly"
        End If
        If ChkboxCreamCheese.Checked = True Then
            AddOns = AddOns & "," & " CreamCheese"
        End If


        Dim Payment As String
        Payment = " "
        If RbtnGcash.Checked = True Then
            Payment = "Gcash"
        End If
        If RbtnDebit.Checked = True Then
            Payment = "Debit Card"
        End If
        If RbtnCoins.Checked = True Then
            Payment = "Coins.ph"
        End If

        If RbtnCash.Checked = True Then
            Payment = "Cash"
        End If

        Dim DiscountRate As Double

        If RbtnPWD.Checked = True Then
            DiscountRate = 0.05

        End If
        If RbtnSenior.Checked = True Then
            DiscountRate = 0.1
        End If
        If RbtnStudent.Checked = True Then
            DiscountRate = 0.03
        End If
        If RbtnDiscountNone.Checked = True Then
            DiscountRate = 0
        End If

        Dim Transaction As String
        Transaction = " "
        If RbtnDelivery.Checked = True Then
            Transaction = "15"
        End If

        If RbtnWalkin.Checked = True Then
            Transaction = "None"
        End If

        TxtTotalAddOn.Text = Val(TxtBlackPearl.Text) + Val(TxtOreo.Text) + Val(TxtNataDeCoco.Text) + Val(TxtCoffeeJelly.Text) + Val(TxtCreamCheese.Text)


        Dim Total As Integer
        Dim DiscountPrice As Double
        Dim AmountPayable As Double


        Total = Val(TxtTotalAddOn.Text) + Val(TxtSizeprice.Text) + Val(TxtDeliveryFee.Text)

        DiscountPrice = Total * DiscountRate

        AmountPayable = (Total - DiscountPrice) * Val(ComboQuantity.Text)

        If AddOns.Length <> 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("********************************" + vbCr + "Troo Tea Ordering System" + vbCr + "********************************" + vbCr + "Choosen DRINK: " + ComboDrink.Text + vbCr + "********************************" + vbCr + "Quantity: " + ComboQuantity.Text + vbCr + "********************************" + vbCr + "Size: " + Sizename + vbCr + "********************************" + vbCr + "Price " + TxtSizeprice.Text + vbCr + "********************************" + vbCr + "AddOns: " + AddOns + vbCr + "********************************" + vbCr + "Total AddOns " + TxtTotalAddOn.Text + vbCr + "********************************" + vbCr + "Delivery Fee" + TxtDeliveryFee.Text + vbCr + "********************************" + vbCr + "Discount " + TxtDiscount.Text + vbCr + "Total " + Total.ToString + vbCr + "Amount Payable: " + AmountPayable.ToString + vbCr + "********************************" + vbCr + "*******************" + vbCrLf + "Thank You For Your Order" + vbCrLf + "*******************")
        End If

        TxtOrderDetails.Text = ("Customer Name: " + TxtCustomername.Text + vbCrLf + "Phone Number: " + TxtPhone.Text + vbCrLf + "Address: " + TxtAddress.Text + vbCrLf + "***********************************************************" + vbCrLf + "Choosen DRINK: " + ComboDrink.Text + vbCrLf + "Quantity: " + ComboQuantity.Text + vbCrLf + "Size: " + Sizename + vbCrLf + "Price: " + TxtSizeprice.Text + vbCrLf + "AddOns: " + AddOns + vbCrLf + "Total AddOns: " + TxtTotalAddOn.Text + vbCrLf + "Delivery Fee: " + TxtDeliveryFee.Text + vbCrLf + "Mode Of Payment: " + Payment + vbCrLf + "Discount Rate for Each Order: " + TxtDiscount.Text + vbCrLf + "Total Price Per Order: " + Total.ToString + vbCrLf + "Amount Payable: " + AmountPayable.ToString + vbCrLf + "***********************************************************" + vbCrLf + "Thank You For Your Order" + vbCrLf + "***********************************************************" + vbCrLf + "Date Of Transaction: " + DateTimePicker1.Text)

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnConfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnConfirm.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you declare a variable within a method, it is only accessible within that method. You'd need to declare it at the class level if you want to have it accessible in multiple methods. You can do some research on **variable scope** when you have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't modify the signature of an event handler, you won't be able to pass the variable from one handler to the other. Instead, declare the variable as a field within the class.

See additional comments added in the code below. I simply cut out some of the code you provided for brevity and shifted the declaration of the `AmountPayable` to outside of the sub it was originally declared in.

You can read more on variable scope [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/how-to-control-the-scope-of-a-variable)

```vb
    Private AmountPayable As Double 'move this declaration outside of the sub

    Private Sub BtnAddOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAddOrder.Click
        Dim Total As Integer
        Dim DiscountPrice As Double

        Total = Val(TxtTotalAddOn.Text) + Val(TxtSizeprice.Text) + Val(TxtDeliveryFee.Text)

        DiscountPrice = Total * DiscountRate

        'variable can be assigned here
        AmountPayable = (Total - DiscountPrice) * Val(ComboQuantity.Text)

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnConfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnConfirm.Click
        MessageBox.Show("Your Total is $" & AmountPayable) 'variable can be accessed here
    End Sub
End Class
```